# Text Font style not appear

Tags: android, text-styling

I am developing one application in which comic font are used and that can be fetched from assets folder. Now I would like to make the text bold.  So I simply use :

```
 Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/comic.TTF"); 
    la = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.la);
    la.setText("Dog");

    la.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(),R.style.boldText);
    la.setTypeface(face);
```

**String.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World, timerTest!</string>
    <string name="app_name">timerTest</string>

    <style name="boldText">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

So the problem is when I run project comic.ttf get properly but bold style does not appear on `text`

Comment: i think when we are using custom font then we cant use any font style...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/comic.TTF"); 

        la = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.la);
        la.setText("Dog");
        la.setTypeface(face,Typeface.BOLD);
```